# json file to handlebars

Tags: android, json, handlebars.js, html-framework-7

I am developing a android app with framework7 which will show some info for vehicles. The first screen will contain a list with the vehicles types and the user can choose one type and then go to the next screen with the subcategories.I want to show the contexts of each set in a website using handlebars "{{}}". I did the first screen with the types but I was wondering if it is possible to use the handlebars to show the subcategories of each vehicle type in a different row(which the user will press and take him to the next page, which will have info for the subtype the user selected).
i have a json file with the following code:

```
    [
    { "id" : 1,
      "Vehicle type": "Hatchback"
      "Subtypes": "st1", "st2", "st3"
    },
    { "id" : 1,
      "Vehicle type": "motorcycle"
      "Subtypes": "mt1", "mt2", "mt3"
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the handlebars {{}}, you need to have a template

1. For example:

   ```
   <script id="template" type="text/template7">
       {{#each records}}
           <p>Vehicle type is:  {{Vehicle type}} </p>
       {{/each}}
   </script>
   ```
2. Compile the template with Template7:

   ```
   var template = $$('#template').html();
   var compiledTemplate = Template7.compile(template);
   ```
3. Get your JSON data from the server:

   ```
   $$.getJSON('link/to/your/json', {}, function (data) {          
       var context = data;
   }
   ```
4. Now render the compiled template by passing required context

   ```
   var html = compiledTemplate(context);
   ```

Now, the `html` variable will contain the html you need. For example:

```
    <p>Vehicle type is: Hatchback</p>
    <p>Vehicle type is: motorcycle</p>
```

N.B. This code has not been tested. And 'records' in the first step needs to be replaced by the root node in your JSON file.

Comment: I did these the problem i have is I want something like a statement  printing each subcategory to the next page!

Comment: Aha! In that case, you can use `data[0]` or `data[1]` etc. as the `context`. You also need a different template for that, but this way you can select which entry you want to display.

Comment: is there any example i can see?